# Trouble accessing a nested JSON value with PYJQ

Tags: json, nested, jq

```
{
"response": {
    "status": "ok",
    "userTier": "developer",
    "total": 18398,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "pages": 1840,
    "orderBy": "relevance",
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "world/2020/jul/03/coronavirus-the-week-explained",
            "type": "article",
            "sectionId": "world",
            "sectionName": "World news",
            "webPublicationDate": "2020-07-03T11:03:46Z",
            "webTitle": "Coronavirus: the week explained",
            "webUrl": "https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/jul/03/coronavirus-the-week-explained",
            "apiUrl": "https://content.guardianapis.com/world/2020/jul/03/coronavirus-the-week-explained",
            "fields": {
                "bodyText": "words"
            },
            "isHosted": false,
            "pillarId": "pillar/news",
            "pillarName": "News"
        },
        {
            "id": "music/2020/jun/10/saving-classical-music-from-coronavirus",
            "type": "article",
            "sectionId": "music",
            "sectionName": "Music",
            "webPublicationDate": "2020-06-10T17:38:03Z",
            "webTitle": "Saving classical music from coronavirus | Letters",
            "webUrl": "https://www.theguardian.com/music/2020/jun/10/saving-classical-music-from-coronavirus",
            "apiUrl": "https://content.guardianapis.com/music/2020/jun/10/saving-classical-music-from-coronavirus",
            "fields": {
                "bodyText": "more words"
            },
            "isHosted": false,
            "pillarId": "pillar/arts",
            "pillarName": "Arts"
        }  
    }
```

The code I use can access WebUrl and webPublicationDate, however I am interested in the bodyText value. To access these values I am using pyjq.

data = response.json()
query=f'.response .results [] | {{web_url: .webUrl, pub_date: .webPublicationDate}}'

output=pyjq.all(query,data)

^This code will extract the webUrl, and PublicationDate. However I want to extract the bodyText. How would I write a query in the same format to grab the bodyText?

Comment: Please fix the example so that it is valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

A jq query for retrieving the .bodyText values as a stream is:

```
.response.results[] | .fields.bodyText
```

Comment: thanks, if I wanted to store the .bodyTexts values in a dictionary how would I do that?

Comment: What would the keys be?

Comment: query=f'.response .results [] | {{web_url: .webUrl, pub_date: .webPublicationDate}}'      
 I think I would structure it in the same way I did this one, I believe this returns a list of dictionaries, and the keys are 'web_url',and 'pub_date'. so the keys for the .bodyText could be anything. Could be 'text'.

Comment: `for i in range(len(output)):  dict=output[i]  date=dict["pub_date"]. url=dict["web_url"] `

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to put a linebreak in that code, but that is how I access the items I get back from the jq. @peak